# How to configure spring security in the simplest case correctly?

Tags: java, spring

I have the controller:

```
@Controller
public class SecurityController{

    @RequestMapping(value="/403")
    public String renderAccessDeniedPage(){
        return "403";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin")
    public String renderAdminWelcomePage(){
        return "admin/welcome";
    }
}
```

It was supposed to render security views when a request is beung redireceted to them by spring-security. I have the following configureation:

`web.xml`

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/coreContext.xml /WEB-INF/securityContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

ant the `securityContext` itself:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="admin/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/" username-parameter="user" password-parameter="pass" login-processing-url="/" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="xaDataSource" 
        authorities-by-username-query="select name, role from users where name = ?" 
        users-by-username-query="select name, password, enabled from users_auth where name = ?" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

The issue is when I trying to send a request to render a page via a browser I just got the page I requested (`admin.jsp` for instance) even if I wasn't be logged in. I tried to debug, and I noticed that no one method of the `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy` I declared in the `web.xml` was called. What's wrong?

Comment: try changing `<security:intercept-url pattern="admin/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />` to `<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />`

Comment: @AlanBarrows Tried, everything's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to AlanBarrows comment (use `<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**"`), you should also map the filter to `/*` instead of `/` :

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

PS : nice to have noticed the relevant info : *no one method of DelegatingFilterProxy was called*

Comment: Wait, I just tried to understand what the pattern specified in the filter-chain's url-mapping means. I thought it might have been called one of the methods...

Comment: Eventually that was the problem. Now I've changed it and it works, thank you.